# How to read a certificate from a USB token in C#

Tags: c#, usb, token, certificate

I have a USB token containing an encryption certificate which has a public key and private key. Now I want to create an application in C# through which I can find out the accessible certificate information. When I plug the USB token in, it is being detected, but no drive has been shown on the computers segment as it happens with the flash drives.

How can I read the certificate from the USB drive?

Comment: This answer might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8424686/1373170

Comment: thanks Pablo... I am looking for something more specific... still this provides me some good information

Comment: No prob. Also you may want to look for a vendor specific api for the device you have, or expand your question with more specific details on the device and what you'd want to get and I'm sure somebody will be able to help you out ;)

Comment: In case of web application, refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885

Answer (score 6):

You can browse through a list of certificates with `X509Store` class. It will give you not only the certification in you USB, but also in your computer. Then with `X509Certificate2UI` you can select the right certificate from a graphical UI list.

This implementation example works fine to get started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui(v=vs.110).aspx