# Cannot find a code to read USB Tokens in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to build a web application where Client will need to sign the data being uploaded with the digital signature. Now these digital signs are USB tokens, which when you install are stored in X.509 stores (my best guess).

I researched a lot, and found that what this guy explains he has done in C#, is what I need to do in Javascript: [C# code for reading X.509 Certificate Store](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10191019/how-to-access-a-certificate-in-a-smart-card-using-the-class-x509store.aspx) and like this thread explains how to retrieve the certificates [C# code to retrieve certificate from USB Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444468/how-to-read-a-certificate-from-a-usb-token-in-c-sharp). But this is all C# and I am unable to find any relevant code in JavaScript.

I can see examples where people are talking about how to encrypt etc, but I couldn't find the explanation on how we can hold on the information in USB Token.

This is the exact process:

1) User opens my webpage on chrome, some data is already there.

2)This data has to be signed digitally

3) user inserts his thumb/usb token device

4) My page detects the signature in signatures list

5) user selects the signature

6) My code reads the signature

7) I use the digital signature to sign the data (which I still need to
    figure out how to do that).

I know there are applications which are doing it already, and probably built in php/java/.net. Any help?

Comment: read that one too, but it was more than a year back and it looks like the crypto API is not ready yet. So does it mean it's not possible???

Comment: Exactly. See my answer here for alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/a/46194323/6371459